# Can I use GnuPG 2 and GnuPG 1 concurrently, seeing the same keys?

Tags: debian, dpkg, gpg, key-authentication, compatibility

Here on a Debian system I use mainly `gpg2`. Some (Debian packaging/signing) tools use `gpg1` internally, and changing them as it should be would be infeasible.

Both my gpg versions are using the same work directory (`~/.gnupg`) and their databases / configuration seem mainly compatible. An exception for this is the handling of the private keys.

As I experienced, private keys created by `gpg2` are not visible for `gpg1` (but their public pairs are).

Digging a lot on the net, as I understand, the `gpg` versions are using different files (and maybe different formats) below `~/.gnupg` to store them. There are also various one-line solutions to convert the `gpg2` database to `gpg1` and vice versa.

Now I have to use mainly `gpg2`, but I have to allow also `gpg1` to work. My idea for this task is that

1. I export the gpg2 private key database.
2. I import it with `gpg1`.

The expected result would be that I can see the same public and private keys with both gpg versions.

Is it possible? Could it work? How can I do that?

(Note: at least Ubuntu and Mint uses already `gpg2` for packaging tasks, but Debian still doesn't.)

Comment: Which tools still need gpg1? I see `devscripts` in Jessie still does, but you could use the backported version instead. `dpkg` and the related tools are fine in Jessie as-is.

Comment: Thanks! I will do. For example, my `debsign` wants still gpg1. Earlier I had trouble also with some debhelper scripts, and also with apt, I don't know if they still exist. Actually, I want to exterminate gpg1 and show its place with salt, now the problem is that I should recompile many .deb development tools for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GnuPG 1.4, 2.0 and 2.1 all support the "good old" `pubring.gpg` file for storing public keys. As long as a `pubkey.gpg` exists, also GnuPG 2.1 will continue to use it and not create a public keyring in the new keybox format.

There are differences with respect to private keys, though. While GnuPG 1.4 and 2.0 both store private keys in the `secring.gpg` file, GnuPG 2.1 merges those into the public keyring file, such that GnuPG 2.1 (`gpg2`, on newer distributions also `gpg`) and GnuPG 1.4 (`gpg1` if available, on older distributions also `gpg`) do not share a common secret keyring store any more (but still can do for the public keyring, as already explained).

If you export the secret keys from `gpg2` and import them to `gpg`/`gpg1`, you should be able to use them from both implementations. GnuPG 1.4 does not mind that secret keys are stored in your `pubring.gpg` file. Be aware GnuPG 1.4 cannot merge secret key packets; if you change your subkeys in GnupG 2.1 and want to copy them to GnuPG 1.4 agein, you will have to delete the secret key from GnuPG 2.1 and import it again. Always make a backup copy before changing anything!